# Objective-c AES CBC decryption with IV

Tags: objective-c, encryption, aes, pkcs#7, cbc-mode

I have been struggling with this problem for several days now and i can't seem to figure it out

I tried using CCCrypt to decrypt an encrypted string, I have the encrypted string encoded with Base64 encode, I have the key and the iv. The encryption is AES256 CBC with PKCS7Padding.

This is the code i am using right now:

```
- (NSData *)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key
{
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128+1];
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr));

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc( bufferSize );

    unsigned char *iv = [@"IV String" cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;

    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt,
                                      kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                      kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                      keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                      iv,
                                      [self bytes],
                                      dataLength,
                                      buffer,
                                      bufferSize,
                                      &numBytesDecrypted);

    if( cryptStatus == kCCSuccess )
    {
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
    }

    free( buffer );
    return nil;
}
```

But `cryptStatus` keeps returning 0 and I couldn't find a way to figure out why.
What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand.  `kCCSuccess` is equal to 0. Why do you think it is failing?

Comment: Um, `kCCSuccess` is 0.

Comment: Your code has other problems though. For example, your `keyPtr` is 16+1 bytes long, but you tell `CCCrypt` that it's `KCCKeySizeAES256`, or 32, bytes long.